# Crosswalkのサイズについて

Tags: monaca

MonacaでCrosswalk版のコンパイルをした場合、Monacaサイトの説明では10M程サイズが増えるとありますが、実際試したところ50M以上ファイルサイズが大きくなりました。（3M→60M）
これはサイト説明が古く最新だとそれくらい増えるのが通常なのでしょうか。それとも10M程度に抑える手段が何かあるのでしょうか。
Crosswalkは使いたいのですが、さすがに一般公開するにはサイズが大きくて。。。